# My Second search is not working using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, search

I am currently using two apis tmdb and omdb

The tmdb search runs and returns all titles for a given search i then want to run a second search using one of those titles by clicking the more info button beside it.

That search is using omdb but it is not running when i click the button nothing happens

I have also include my code so u can run it yourselfs to better understand and hopefully help me with my problem 
here is a screenshot of the search so far so it is easyier to understand what i mean

[image]

code below

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Seach</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
    mode = 'search/movie',
    input,
    movieName,
    key = '?api_key=API KEY';

    $('#search').click(function() {
        var input = $('#movie').val(),
            movieName = encodeURI(input);
        $.ajax({
            url: url + mode + key + '&query='+movieName ,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {

        var table = '<table>';
        $.each( data.results, function( key, value ) {
          table += '<tr><td class="results-img"><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + value.poster_path +'" alt="" width="150" height="200"></td><td class="results-title">' + value.original_title + '</td><td class="results-date">' + value.release_date + 
          '</td><td class="results-search-btn"><button class="search-btn" id="MoreInfo">Few More Info</button></td></tr>';
        });
        $('#searchresult').html(table);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
<script text="text/javascript">
// When the more button is click this runs a search using the title of the movie it is next to  
$('.search-btn').live('click', '.search-btn', function() {
    getImdbInfo( $(this).closest('td').prev('.results-title').text() );
});

//The function below takes the entered title and searchs imdb for a match then it displays as followed

function getImdbInfo(Title) {
    var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + Title;
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data) {

            var str = "";
            str += "<h2>Title :" +data.Title+ "</h2>";
            str += "<p>Plot :" +data.Plot+ "</p>";

            $("#chosenresult").html(str);
      },
      error: function (request, status, error) { alert(status + ", " + error); }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Movie Search</h1>
<input id="movie" type="text" /><button id="search">Search</button>
</center>
<div id="chosenresult"></div>
<div id="searchresult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in jQuery 1.5.x you don't have `.on()` since that was only available in jQuery 1.7 according to the [specs](https://api.jquery.com/on/). Instead, if you are bound to the version 1.5 you should use `.delegate()`. If jQuery version is not an issue try jQuery 1.10 by simply changing the version in the CDN path you use.

Further more, a delegate function relies on binding the event to the parent node.
Since `document` is not a real node try using `document.body`
In your example:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'search-btn', function(){});
```

Or in jQuery 1.5 it's a little reversed:

```
$(document.body).delegate('search-btn', 'click', function(){});
```

For your title issue try using this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.results-title').text();
```

Comment: the above answer has sovled the button problem now the problem is that the title is not being runned i am just getting undefined !!

Comment: That makes current answers sound off-topic but ok ^^

Comment: what ? my problem was the button was not working therefore i was unable to see if the search was working right sry to be a problem any soluton u  can think of

Comment: Indeed your problem was the click event on the button, so you'll get answers for just that. Problem becomes larger when this question gets search indexed and people try to find solutions to a similar problem and find answers related to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `on` was only added in `jQuery 1.7`. If you want to use `jQuery 1.5` use `live` instead :

```
$('.search-btn').live('click', '.search-btn', function() {
    getImdbInfo( $(this).closest('td').prev('.results-title').text() );
});
```

Instead of :

```
$(document).on('click', '.search-btn', function() {
    getImdbInfo( $(this).closest('td').prev('.results-title').text() );
});
```

Comment: i tryed changeing it and now the second search is running but i am getting undefined when trying to bring the plot i dont think it is reading the right title ?????

Comment: $(this).closest('td').prev('.results-title').text() seems to return an empty value...

Comment: yeah i need it to return the movie title the button is next to i have edited the above code with ur fix but i am still getting undifned

Comment: Try what Tim Vermealen said : $(this).closest('tr').find('.results-title').text();